# Can not open manually compiled shared object file

Tags: compiling, shared-library

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to /usr/local/lib

```
blahblah@test:~$ ls -al /usr/local/lib
total 1392
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4096  .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root    4096  ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12  libglfw.so -> libglfw.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      14  libglfw.so.3 -> libglfw.so.3.3
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  335888  libglfw.so.3.3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      23  libsfml-graphics.so -> libsfml-graphics.so.2.5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      25  libsfml-graphics.so.2.5 -> libsfml-graphics.so.2.5.1
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  475800  libsfml-graphics.so.2.5.1
```

When I use SFML library, it works well. But when use GLFW, compiler return error message.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libglfw.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If i run program with setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH like below, it works well again. 
I don't know what happens here.

```
blahblah@test:~$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./my_program
```

Comment: Did you `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? otherwise it's just a local shell variable that won't be inherited by child environments

Comment: @steeldriver I added ```export LD_LIBRARY_PATH``` on .bash_profile. Should i need to add  export on anohter file?

Comment: Let's back up here a moment: is `error while loading shared libraries` a runtime errror or a buildtime error? what exactly is the command that produces it?

Comment: @steeldriver it's runtime error. i just execute sample test code like ```./test```